# Loading a model from mlflow with pyfunc returns error TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class create_pyfunc_wrapper with abstract method predict

Tags: python, mlflow

I have a model that has not been edited since September this year that is used daily by a pipeline. Suddenly today this line of code

```
model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri=f"models:/{model_name}/{stage}")
```

is returning error TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class create_pyfunc_wrapper with abstract method predict

Do anyone has any idea about how to fix this issue?

I noticed now from the logs that yesterday 2023-12-05 mlflow was on version 2.8.1, while today 2023-12-06 on version 2.9.0

Fixed with

```
%pip install mlflow==2.8.1
```